# ruby on rails one function in controller have different views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
 class HellosController < ApplicationController


  def index
  #do sth here 
  end

  def new
    #do sth here
  end

  def edit
    #do sth here
  end

  def report
  #how can I  display  different format of report according to diff value of a variable ?      
  end

end
```

I know each different function in controller can have a view,now I have this report link to a report view.I need to add a view of report for this project.

How can I display different view according to an variable say @reportType ?
What I need to add to controller?How should I name the added report view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `@report_type` in `report.html.erb`

For example :
In **report.html.erb**

```
<% if @report_type == "this" %>
<%= render partial: "this" %>
<% elsif @report_type == "that" %>
<%= render partial: "that" %>
<% end %>
```

Here you will have two partials like

**_this.html.erb** and **_that.html.erb**

In this way you can have multiple view of a proper page with respect to the report type.

Answer (score 1):

In controller you can render different pages with if condition

Eg:

```
if [condition]
  render "abc"
else
  render "xyz"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough. A bare-bones example of such thing could be:

```
class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @report = Report.find(params[:report_id])
    if @report.type == "special"
      # This will render app/view/special_report.html.erb
      render :special_report
    else
      # This will render app/view/report.html.erb
      render :report
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, there's a lot more than that, [look at the Rails guides for other options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render). Notice I'm using symbols in order to specify views. You don't have to do the same, strings are okay too, like `"report"` and `"special_report"`.

Answer (score 0):

in your link send `report_id` as parameter

```
= link_to "See report", your_report_path + "?report_id=" + report.id
```

In your `report` action

```
def report
  @reportType = ReportModel.find params(:report_id)
end
```

In `report.html.erb` you can use this variable, e.g.

```
Name of the report is <%= @reportType.name %>
```

Comment: Thank you!could you explain more?I dont have any link in my report,and in my view its called report.html.erb -- I think they are linked by name convension.How to change this name link to your method?and for a second view of report where to add it and how to name it?

Comment: how are you going to report page, by clicking some link right?

Comment: I have put content of report in question,It seems no link there...in app when I click a button called report, report page will show